# Routing is still using the main table after I configured it to use a custom routing table

Tags: networking, router, arp

I have the following situation:

```
- - - - - - -
| namespace |-------o      o------
- - - - - - -     vethY   ppp0
          vethX
```

where:

- `ppp0` is a PPP interface and its ip address is 192.168.100.169/24
- `vethX` is a virtual ethernet interface inside the namespace and its ip address is 10.0.0.3/24
- `vethY` is an other virtual ethernet inteface, its ip address is 10.0.0.5/24 and it is also the default gateway for the namespace

In fact the routing table into the namespace is the following:

```
$ sudo ip netns exec my_namespace ip route
default via 10.0.0.5 dev vethX
10.0.0.0/24 dev vethX proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.3
```

I want to use policy based routing in this scenario; in particular I want to use a custom routing table when the incoming interface of network packets is the `vethY` or the `ppp0` interface.

I've created the custom routing table with name '**T1**' adding the entry "T1" in the file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.
Then I've added the policy routing rule that will tell the system when to use this new routing table.
So now the policy routing rules are:

```
$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all iif ppp0 lookup T1
32765:  from all iif vethY lookup T1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  form all lookup default
```

Then I've added the following rules into my custom table

```
$ ip route show table T1
default via 192.168.100.169 dev ppp0
10.0.0.0/24 dev vethY scope link
192.168.100.180 dev ppp0 scope link
```

The last line shows which is the other endpoint of the point-to-point link. 
Besides, the main routing table is empty.

With this configuration, if I am into the namespace and I ping 10.0.0.5, I don't receive answers (neither the ARP reply).
Request packets reach the vethY interface (I've seen that using wireshark) but no answer is generated.
If my arp cache is empty, when an arp request is sent no arp reply will be sent back.

Instead, if I add the rule
`10.0.0.0/24 dev vethY scope link` 
also into the main table, all the packets flow in the correct way.

Why I don't receive answers if I don't add this rule into the main table? 
Why is the main table involved, since I configured the routing to use T1 for all the packets coming either from vethY or ppp0?

Comment: IIRC ping answers to local interfaces use the `local` table as well (the details were complicated and I've forgotten them). Also, IIRC, the local table may be updated automatically under some circumstances, so check if there are differences in the local table when you add the rule to the main table (too lazy to try this myself just now).